# Why Python didn't throw RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration, while python3 did?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}
for key, val in dict.items():
    if key == "b":
        dict["e"] = 5
for key, val in dict.items():
    print (key, val)
```

above code when executed in python3 it shows following error

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
    for key, val in dict.items():
Line 4 in solve (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().solve(param_1, param_2)
Line 33 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 44 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Where as the above code runs without error in python(version earlier that 3) and with following expected output.

```
('a', 1)
('c', 3)
('b', 2)
('e', 5)
('d', 4)
```

Is it due to this?
[As of Python version 3.7, dictionaries are ordered. In Python 3.6 and earlier, dictionaries are unordered.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp#:%7E:text=not%20allow%20duplicates.-,As%20of%20Python%20version%203.7%2C%20dictionaries%20are%20ordered.%20In%20Python%203.6%20and%20earlier%2C%20dictionaries%20are%20unordered.,-Dictionaries%20are%20written)

Comment: No... that isn't the reason... Altering the size of the dictionary has thrown an error since 3.0 from what I can remember  I don't know what the real reason is

Comment: @alexpdev python2 raised an exception when changing the size of a dict too. The difference is that `dict.keys()` and `dict.items()` returned lists, so you were not iterating over the dict when iterating over the keys/items. If you want to do something similar in python3, make a list of items: `items = list(dict.items())` then iterated over `items`.

Comment: @mark Why are you telling me?  I didn't ask the question.... Sounds like you have enough knowledge to answer the OP's question

Comment: @alexpdev I'm telling you because you left a comment that was completely wrong.

Comment: @mark  How is my comment wrong?  I accurately stated that changing the size of the dictionary has been in effect since 3.0.... and I said I don't know about the rest... Which part of the is wrong?

Comment: It's wrong because changing the size of a dict you were iterating over was an error in python2 as well. `for key in somedict: del somedict[k]` is an error in python2. It was not introduced in version 3. See error [here](https://paiza.io/projects/snDtgUHoU1Od4qSAv2H75A?language=python)

Comment: what is dp? you cannot define . If you define dp or you can use dict instead of DP it can shows you an error.

Comment: To say it was an error **since** 3.0 implies it was not an error before 3.0. If you didn't mean to suggest this was a different behavior since 3.0, your first comment makes no sense in the context of a question asking about behavior differences between the two versions.

Comment: I didn't answer because it's a dupe @alexpdev — just taking a while to find [because ....](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: @j1-lee Sorry for the spelling mistake in "dp["e"] = 5". I meant "dict["e"] = 5".